# Notation for infinite sums with finitely many non-zero summands

Tags: notation

Is there a standard notation for infinite sums
$
\sum_{\nu} a_{\nu}
$
having all but finitely many zero summands?

I remember to have seen somewhere the notation
$
\sum'_{\nu} a_{\nu}
$
(adding an apostrophe as a superscript to the sum symbol),
but I wonder whether this is standard, or there is some other more standard notation for this situation.

Thank you.

Comment: It is not really a property of the sum but of the terms, so usually I would just make a note that they satisfy this.

Comment: (and sometimes, I will not even make that note and just assume the reader can also see that this is the case).